# android - removing item from ListView on long click

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm having some troubles while trying to remove an item from the list view on long click. Below is the code:

```
public class MListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

private ListView lv;
private String[] some_data = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    some_data = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mdata);

    // Bind resources Array to ListAdapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, some_data);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setDividerHeight(3);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            // Can't manage to remove an item here

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Be more specific. Errors, stack traces, what's not working, what can't you manage?

Comment: You should consider using this if you have an action bar in you application http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu in addition to the answer of @TNR

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Arrays`, you should use `ArrayList` to remove and add items to a `Listview`.

Once the Array size is declared you can modify the data in particular index but cannot remove the items or add to it.

So Take an ArrayList and just when you long click on the ListView Item, just call remove method of Arraylist and notify the data set changed.

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

inside your longclick write the below code to remove item.

```
al.remove(arg2);//where arg2 is position of item you click
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 12):

try

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {

              myAdapter.remove(some_data[position]);
              myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: throws an UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: exactly was I was looking for. If you are using a ListView or any subclass of it, use the method above to get the held item from the list

Answer (score 0):

I had issues using this method. and i solved it using this.

```
            listStat.remove(listStat.get(arg2));
            lvStat.requestLayout();
            adapterStat.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think this will help to others.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. What is `lvStat` here in your code ?

Comment: @pc listview reference

Comment: I have `VideoView`, `ImageView` and `TextView` in my ListView. Its working for `ImageView` and `TextView` but not for `VideoView`

Answer (score 0):

```java
itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        view.getContext(),
        androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        itemViewModel.getItems().getValue().stream().map(TaskCard::getTitle).collect(Collectors.toList())
);
ListView listview = view.findViewById(R.id.item_listview);
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
        itemAdapter.remove(itemAdapter.getItem(i));
        return true;
    }
});
```