# remove item onlongclick from listview

Tags: android, listview

I want when long pressing an item of my list to give an option **delete** and delete the item if it pressed.

```
//onCreate()
alreadyAddedFood = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alreadyAddedList);
registerForContextMenu(alreadyAddedFood); 

//END of onCreate()

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_general, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.delete){
          //How to delete?
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"delete"+item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I also have this class which i implement the onlongClickListener and it works fine but without giving the user the option to press delete like the photo below

```
 public void alreadyAdded(String searchedMessage) {

        itemsAdded.add(searchedMessage);

        final ArrayAdapter<String>addedAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemsAdded);
        alreadyAddedFood.setAdapter(addedAdapter);

     alreadyAddedFood.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                itemsAdded.remove(position);
//                addedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
//                Toast.makeText(AddFood.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                return true;
//            }
//        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: take a look at this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340579/android-removing-item-from-listview-on-long-click

Comment: You neeed to remove item using `ARRAYLIST.remove(position);` and after that u need to use the `notifyDataChange();`

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha i did that(on other function) but i also want the option "delete"to be implemented.Is there i way i can what you told me  on "onContextItemSelected" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `onContextItemSelected` :

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); // init the info to get the position from
items.remove(info.position); // remove the item from the list 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //updating the adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Something like this:

```
private ListView ls;
 ls.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


    ls.remove(arg2);//where arg2 is position of item you click
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pop up a dialog and ask the user for his confirmation.
However, it is less aesthetic. I would recommend one of these:

1. After the long click, show a delete option (using the delete icon rather than text) in the app-bar.
2. Do not support long click, instead use an swipe-able rows with a delete option (again, with an icon) in the right/left of each row. (I will recommend [this](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) library.

[image: picture taken from the library page on github]
(gif was taken from [here](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView))

Comment: Please read exactly what he is asking for, if there is no solution then you can give him other solution.